# Accessing logs in Manage Files area

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a way to access files, such as those created by the CCB tool, that are placed into a specific directory in the Manage Files area of a course offering? I've tried the topic API, but the new /file path only returns a value when the file is attached to a topic - not if it's just "hanging out" in the files area. Is there a more generic way to access the entire file structure there - maybe even by using WebDAV)? If so, is there a way to turn WebDAV on?

Thank you,
-George

Answer (score 1):

The Valence Learning Framework API does not currently offer direct access to the Manage Files area.

I believe that clients can engage D2L to provide WebDAV access to the Manage Files store; the D2L client should contact their account manager to work through the details of setting this up for their use. This is not a feature that a third party integrator can count on all clients having available though, as it does (I believe) require a special engagement with D2L around a client's service.